# Is $S_4 \to S_4$ , $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is a map $S_4 \to S_4$ , $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ isomorphism?

Obviously this map is a bijection. I am unsure if $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$. Possibly no because any $S_n$ is not commutative?

Comment: The equation $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$ is untrue. Let $a=(1\;2)$ and $b=(1\;3)$.

Comment: "because any $S_n$ is not commutative" - yes, except for $n=1,2$. But your title has only $n=4$, so no need here to consider any $S_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ba)^{-1}$$ and since $S_4$ is not commutative the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is not a homomorphism.

---

**Edit:** How do we get $a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ba)^{-1}$?

We have $$ba(ba)^{-1} = e\implies a(ba)^{-1}= b^{-1}\implies (ba)^{-1}= a^{-1}b^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you say more about $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$.  Is this the result of the mapping or the formula to check for isomorphism?

Comment: @Taylor see my answer. It's a property of groups.

Answer (score -1):

Let c = (ab)^-1.

abc = e, the identity element by axiom of a group.

a(bc) = e by axiom of associativity.

a^-1a(bc) = a^-1e.

ebc = a^-1e.

bc = a^-1.

b^-1bc = b^-1a^-1.

c = b^-1a^-1.

Groups are not necessarily abelian, so it may or may not be.

Comment: The question is about the specific group $S_4$, not the general situation, so while relevant this isn't completely an answer.